# Navbar width is not screen when it responsive vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

So I want to make my navbar is screen width whenever the screen width is changed, I already use `w-screen` on each div or element but it still wont full scree,
please see the gif

[image: navbar]

this is the components

```
<template>
    <header class="w-screen">
        <Navbar class="sticky max-w-full top-0 z-50"></Navbar>
    </header>
    <div class="bg-primary-focus border-4 border-yellow-400">
        <div class="flex flex-row w-screen h-screen border-2 border-purple-700">
            <div
                class="h-full overflow-x-visible"
                :class="{
                    'w-[10%]': showTime == true,
                    'w-[40%]': showTime == false,
                }"
            >
                <Menu
                    @SidebarShow="getSidebar($event)"
                    :Payload="payload"
                    :Content="content"
                    :Plants="plants"
                    :Algaes="algae"
                    :NutDefs="nutrientDef"
                ></Menu>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full h-full">
                
                <Detail
                    :Desc="content"
                    :Payload="payload"
                    :FavData="favData"
                    :State="state"
                    class="bg-primary-focus text-neutral-focus"
                ></Detail>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

the Navbar.vue

```
<template>
    <div data-themes="foliage">
        <header class="navbar bg-base-200 w-screen">
            <div class="flex-none">
                <div class="drawer">
                    <input
                        id="my-drawer"
                        type="checkbox"
                        class="drawer-toggle"
                    />
                    <div class="drawer-content">
                        <!-- Page content here -->
                        <label
                            for="my-drawer"
                            class="btn btn-square btn-ghost drawer-button"
                        >
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                fill="none"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                class="inline-block w-5 h-5 stroke-current"
                            >
                                <path
                                    stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                                    stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                                ></path>
                            </svg>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drawer-side">
                        <label for="my-drawer" class="drawer-overlay"></label>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-1">
                <a href="/">
                    <img
                        src="/images/logo.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="btn rounded-md btn-ghost normal-case invisible xl:visible md:visible sm:invisible"
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div v-if="!NoAuthLink" class="px-5">
                <div
                    v-if="$page.props.auth.user?.name"
                    class="menu flex-row-reverse"
                >
                    
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    <Link :href="route('login')">
                        <p class="btn btn-ghost">Sign in</p>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</template>
```